# Can I still enter UAE with the remaining 5 days left?

Tags: visas, dubai

i got UAE long term visa of 90 days on January 30/01/2019 and it will expire on march 30/03/2019 and i have not yet move out of country till date , it remain just 5 days left to expire..my questions is that can i still enter UAE with this very Visa ?

Answer (score 1):

If you have proof that you are leaving within that 5 days, for instance if you're driving in from Saudi Arabia and have a flight out from Dubai two days later, then sure.

If it expired in March however then it is finished.